# Create palindrom function without append function in output in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

i am trying to create palyndrom function which is doing palyndrom from input string. Something like this: `(palindrome '(1 2 3 4)) ==> (1 2 3 4 3 2 1).`

I have created this code below but it is returning me `(palindrome '(1 2 3 4)) ==> (1 (2 (3 (4) 3) 2) 1)`

My code is below. Task is to NOT use append or reverse.

```
  (define (palindrome l)
  (cond
           ((null? (cdr l)) (list (car l)))
        ((list (car l) (palindrome (cdr l)) (car l)))))
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Perhaps you can make your own `reverse` and `append`?

Comment: When i add my own append it doesnot works.

Comment: Code of append:

`(define (append2 lst1 lst2)
  (if (null? lst1)
      lst2
      (cons (car lst1) 
            (append2 (cdr lst1) lst2))))`

Whe i pust append instead of list it says: 

`append2: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 2
  given: 3
  arguments...:`

Comment: With "native" append it works fine. So there will be probably something more what native append is doing.

Comment: Well.. If you make `append` that takes 2 arguments and need to append 3 lists you do `(append2 lst1 (append2 lst2 lst3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment of Sylwester, you can do your own version of `append` or `reverse`. Here is an example in which only the `append` function (called `concatenate`) is defined.

```
(define (palindrome l)
  (define (concatenate l1 l2)
    (if (null? l1)
        l2
        (cons (car l1) (concatenate (cdr l1) l2))))
  (define (p l)
    (cond ((null? l) '())
          ((null? (cdr l)) l)
          (else (cons (car l) (concatenate (p (cdr l)) (list (car l)))))))
  (p l))

(palindrome '(1 2 3 4))

'(1 2 3 4 3 2 1)
```

Here instead is a tail recursive version:

```
(define (palindrome l)
  (define (concatenate l1 l2)
    (if (null? l1)
        l2
        (cons (car l1) (concatenate (cdr l1) l2))))
  (define (p l prefix suffix)
    (cond ((null? l) (concatenate prefix suffix))
          ((null? (cdr l)) (concatenate prefix (cons (car l) suffix)))
          (else (p (cdr l) (concatenate prefix (list (car l))) (cons (car l) suffix)))))
  (p l '() '()))
```